# VS2013 Setup Project Error

Tags: .net

I am using VS2013.
I have created setup project in VS2013.
I have set framework dependency as 4.0 only. 
When I installing this setup on client PC, it is giving error as "This setup requires the .NET Framework version 4.5. Please install the .NET framework and run this setup again........"

Even I have set prerequisites as 4.0 in prerequisites windows. No any other prerequisites selected. Though I am facing this issue.
Even while creating setup project I have selected .Net Framework 4.0 also.
What I am missing. Please reply as soon as possible.